# django-jinja: intcomma filter not found

Tags: django, jinja2

I want to use django's humanize library in jinja2.
I have my settings configured as described in the [django-jinja documentation](https://niwinz.github.io/django-jinja/latest/#_humanize)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_jinja',
    'django_jinja.contrib._humanize',
    ...
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'extensions': DEFAULT_EXTENSIONS + [
                ...
            ],
            ...
        },
    },
]

USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
)
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('nl', gettext('Dutch')),
    ('de', gettext('German')),
)
```

But when I use `{{ somevalue|intcomma }}` in one of my Jinja2 templates I get the error:

`django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: ("no filter named 'intcomma'",)`

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What you are trying to do with `intcomma`??

Comment: Display 1000000 as 1.000.000. I want to use more of the humanize library as well.

Answer (score 1):

A solution to this would be to override the environment function in jinja2.py to include intcomma (or any other filter that Django comes with). This does not require django-jinja.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage
from django.urls import reverse
from jinja2 import Environment
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import intcomma

def environment(**options):
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url': reverse,
        'intcomma': intcomma,
    })
    return env
```

And in templates:

```
{{ intcomma(1000000) }}
```